Method to abort Hangfire server at startup
I have an ASP.NET Core project that uses Hangfire with SQL Server storage for recurring jobs. It also has a mechanism for ensuring the database connection is valid and up to date on startup. If there is any issue with the database, a middleware is in place to display a message indicating an issue and stop the application. An abbreviated Program.cs looks like this:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// (Register other services)

builder.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
{
    config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180);
    config.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer();
    config.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings();
    config.UseSqlServerStorage("connectionString");
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

using IServiceScope scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;

IDatabaseService database = services.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseService>();

// Sets a flag if there are any database problems.
await database.EnsureInitializedAsync();

// Checks the flag and displays an error message response,
// short-circuits the Request and shuts down the process.
app.UseMiddleware<DatabaseInitializationMiddleware>();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.Run();

With the addition of Hangfire, the application how repeatedly throws SqlException every 15 seconds if the database connection is invalid, which is something checked in EnsureInitializedAsync(). What I am looking for is a way to stop Hangfire after calling this method if the database has issues so it doesn't constantly try to connect to the database until the application stops.
I have tried adding:
using BackgroundJobServer server = new BackgroundJobServer(JobStorage.Current);
server.SendStop();
await server.WaitForShutdownAsync(default);

after the database initialization check, but this fails with

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Current JobStorage instance has not been initialized yet.


The exception about Current JobStorage instance has not been initialized yet. is throwed from hangfire package. For this issue, you are missing this line.
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

Change your code like below, the hangfire service will work properly.
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.Run();

For more details, you can check my answer in this thread.
